# How to add a caption to a video when sharing a video via WhatsApp using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried to add a text (caption) to a video, which I wanted to share:

```
public void shareVideoWhatsApp()
{
    Intent videoshare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    videoshare.setType("*/*");

    String downloadurl = "Here comes the url";
    videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, downloadurl);

    videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(StorageHandlerSDcard.getPath('v') + "/" + "video.mp4"));

    if(isPackageInstalled("com.whatsapp",this))
    {
        videoshare.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(videoshare, "Share video and caption"));
    }
    else
    {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp is not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The video is shared without the caption. Do you have any idea to share video and caption/text simultaneously via WhatsApp and Intent?

Comment: I think that's not currently possible with video, just with pictures...

Comment: Has anyone tried to contact WhatsApp tech support about this? They haven't documented this in their only FAQ about the topic on here: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012
However, it's working for images, so I don't see the reason why it shouldn't be supported for videos too!